# Securing app with Spring Security doesn't work

Tags: java, spring

I wrote a simple backend software and I wanted to secure it with Spring Security and LDAP. It is obvious that LDAP part of the project works fine. the problem is that when I use the `formLogin()` for entring, that doesn't work and when I use postman it shows the result without asking user name and password! I think something in my`webSecurityConfig` is wrong. this is my `webSecurityConfig` code:

> @Configuration public class WebSecurityConfig extends
>   WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>     http
>             .csrf().disable()
>             .authorizeRequests()
>             .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
>             .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated();
> }
>
> @Override
> public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
>     auth
>             .ldapAuthentication()
>             .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
>             .groupSearchBase("ou=people")
>             .contextSource()
>             .url("ldap://localhost:10389/dc=example,dc=com")
>             .and()
>             .passwordCompare()
>             .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder() {
>             })
>             .passwordAttribute("userPassword");
> } }
> ```

Comment: Did you enable spring-security with `@EnableWebSecurity`? Are you using Spring Boot or just Spring Web MVC?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki where should I add it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`@EnableWebSecurity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html) to enable Spring Security.

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

and remove `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` from your configuration as it matches all the requests. This construct is normally used to specify specific whitelisted endpoints like static documentation that does not require security:

```
.antMatchers("/docs/**").permitAll()
```

Comment: thank you. I have added it. but it wasn't the solution, unfortunately.

Comment: @nozhinatlaskermanshah if you remove `antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` configuration, will it force the authentication?

Comment: thank you. That resolves my problem. please post it as a solution to mark it as a solution. but another minor problem. using form login I can access my services. when I disable my formlogin and try to get results by the postman, I always get access denied results even with correct username and password in the authentication area. now, what is the problem?

Comment: @nozhinatlaskermanshah updated. You probably need `.antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()` or other config to whitelist the parts of URL that handle login forms.